# Supporting nested structures with Spark StructType

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

The javadocs for Spark's [`StructType#add`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/StructType.html#add(java.lang.String,%20org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType)) method show that the second argument needs to be a class that extends `DataType`.

I have a situation where I need to add a fairly complicated `MapType` as a field on a `StructType`.

Specifically, this `MapType` field is a map of several nested structures:

```
Map<String,Map<Integer,Map<String,String>>>
```

Hence it is a map with 2 nested/inner maps. The inner-most map if of type `Map<String,String>` (so in Spark parlance, `MapType[StringType,StringType]`).

The middle map is of type `Map<Integer,Map<String,String>>` (so again in Spark parlance, `MapType[IntegerType,MapType[StringType,StringType]]`).

How do I specify this complex nested structure of maps when calling the `StructType#add` method?

That is, I want to be able to do something like this:

```
var myStruct : StructType = new StructType()
myStruct.add("complex-o-map",
    MapType[StringType,MapType[IntegerType,MapType[StringType,StringType]]])
```

However it only looks like I can add the single outer-most `MapType`:

```
var myStruct : StructType = new StructType()
myStruct.add("complex-o-map", MapType)
```

This makes me sad. How do I specify my nested map structure during the call to `add(...)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "types" expected by `MapType` (.e.g `StringTypes`, `MapType`) aren't really types in the Scala sense, they are *objects*, so you should pass them as constructor arguments and not as type parameters - in other words, use `()` instead of `[]`:

```
val myStruct = new StructType().add("complex-o-map",
  MapType(StringType,MapType(IntegerType,MapType(StringType,StringType))))

myStruct.printTreeString()
// prints:
// root
// |-- complex-o-map: map (nullable = true)
// |    |-- key: string
// |    |-- value: map (valueContainsNull = true)
// |    |    |-- key: integer
// |    |    |-- value: map (valueContainsNull = true)
// |    |    |    |-- key: string
// |    |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```